# Import Issue while importing data with Hyphen

Tags: acumatica

I have written an import scenario for a custom page that stores custom attributes for a serial number. The attributes are stored in a custom table having a Key field InventoryID, LotSerialNbr.
I am trying to populate the data through import scenarios and it should update the custom fields with values as a part of the implementation process.
The serial numbers have – (hyphen) eg. 2022-07-12-001 and while importing it removes the hyphen and inserts a new record in the custom table where it supposes to update the serial number with a hyphen.

Is it default behaviour of acumatica import scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the DAC attribute is the problem.  I have changed PXDBString to LotSerialNbr and it is properly updating the data.

```
#region LotSerialNbr
    public abstract class lotSerialNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _LotSerialNbr;
    //[PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true)]
    //[PXUIField(DisplayName = "LotSerialNbr")]
    [PXDefault()]
    [LotSerialNbr(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "LotSerial Nbr")]
    public virtual string LotSerialNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LotSerialNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LotSerialNbr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```